# Boost::log with static factory methods

Tags: c++, factory, boost-log

I try to implement logging with the boost::log library. I declared loggers as private class members, but uncounted a problem when I came to a class with a static factory method. 
The error message is:
   invalid use of member 'MyObjectContainer::slg' in static member function.
I want to avoid global loggers, is there any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is several solutions.

1)You can use local variable in your static function. Like this:

```
void MyClass::MyStaticmemberFunction()
{
    boost::log::sources::logger my_logger;
    BOOST_LOG(my_logger) << "log message.";
}
```

2)You can transmit pointer to you class object as function parameter. In this case you should also add "get function" to your class. Like this:

```
// regular member function (not static) - "get function"
boost::log::sources::logger_mt MyClass::GetLogger()
{
    return m_member_logger;
}

void MyClass::MyStaticMemberFunction(MyClass *my_class_object)
{
    if (!my_class_object)
    {
        boost::log::sources::logger local_logger;
        BOOST_LOG(local_logger) << "MyStaticFunction:: invalid input data.";
        return;
    }
    BOOST_LOG(my_class_object->GetLogger()) << "log message.";
}
```

Regards.